# How to change the title shown in the window top bar?

Tags: vimscript

`:set title` enable the prompt of the title of the file in the window title.

How can I change the content of this title? For example, I want to give `My pattern` before the filename every time it is edited.  How to modify or change the pattern of title through vim commands?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716644/how-to-change-gvim-titlestring/36717214#36717214

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated in [`:h title`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27title%27):

> When on, the title of the window will be set to the value of
>     'titlestring' (if it is not empty), or to:
>
> filename [+=-] (path) - VIM
>
> Where:
>
> ```
>   filename    the name of the file being edited
>   -       indicates the file cannot be modified, 'ma' off
>   +       indicates the file was modified
>   =       indicates the file is read-only
>   =+      indicates the file is read-only and modified
>   (path)      is the path of the file being edited
>   - VIM       the server name |v:servername| or "VIM"
> ```

So you'll want to modify the content of `titlestring`.

See [`:h 'titlestring'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27titlestring%27) for examples and explanations.

Comment: Everytime, i closed vim, i got a message like 'thanks for using vim'. I wanted to change this. I tried with :au VimLeave * set title titlestring=Mytext as well as :au BufLeave * set title titlestring=Mytext.   But when I close vim, Mytext is not set as the title. Why?

Comment: But that is not what you described in your question, is it? And I have never seen such a message when leaving Vim... You should edit your question with a clear description of your problem, a screenshot of this message and also a description of how you installed Vim because I have never heard of a version which prompted such a message

Comment: Thanks statox. My question is different. I read the help and tried. That works. I just wanted to know whether its possible to change when closing a file

Comment: Regarding your 'thanks for using vim' message, I suggest you read [`:h titleold`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#titleold). Other wise, the comments should not be used to ask new question (but rather add details/ask for precisions on existing question). If you have another issue, please ask another question.